# Necesito mantener un label alineado con el primer div que le siga

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Estoy creando un formulario dentro de un footer y así se ve en distintas resoluciones:

**col-lg-4**:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**col-md-4**  y **col-sm-4**:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**col-xs-12**:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como pueden notar, el label que contiene la palabra "Nuevo:" permanece alineado al input que contiene el "Rut" en todas las resoluciones, excepto en **col-xs-12**. He intentado de alinearlo mediante css pero no doy en el clavo.

No pongo el snipet porque curiosamente no se ve igual que en mi navegador, pero aquí está el código:

**html**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset='utf-8'>
<title>LosTurnos</title>

<!-- Bootstrap CSS-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- Bootstrap Tema opcional -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<!-- Bootstrap JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">

</head>

<body>
<div id="footer">
  <div class="navbar navbar-inner  navbar-fixed-bottom navbar-inverse mifooter">
    <p class="muted credit">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <form id="miform" action="trae_nuevo_empaque.php" class="form-inline">
              <div class="form-group"><label id="nuevito"><span>Nuevo:</span></label>
                <div class="input-group">
                  <div class="input-group-addon">Rut</div>
                  <input type="text" maxlength="8" class="form-control rut" placeholder="8 dígitos" required>
                </div>
                <div class="input-group">
                  <div class="input-group-addon">Nombre</div>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control nombre" placeholder="El primer nombre" required>
                </div>
                <div class="input-group">
                  <div class="input-group-addon">Apellido</div>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Un apellido" required>
                </div>
                <div class="input-group emailpe">
                  <div class="input-group-addon">E-Mail</div>
                  <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="email@algo.algo" required>
                </div>
                <div class="input-group divenviareg">
                  <div class="input-group-addon">Enviar correo de registro</div>
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info enviareg"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i></button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur ullam earum assumend</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Vitae quos ipsa distinctio asp.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**css**:

```
.form-group > #nuevito{
    color: white;
    display: inline-block !important;
}
.form-group #nuevito span{
    padding-right: 10px !important;
    display: inline-block !important;
}
.input-group{
    max-width: 230px;
}
.rut{
    max-width: 134px;
}
.emailpe{
    min-width: 230px;
}
.input-group-addon, .form-control, .enviareg{
    padding-top: 1px;
    padding-bottom: 1px;
    padding-left: 4px;
    padding-right: 6px;
    height: 25px;
}
.enviareg{
    width: 56px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:0px;
    border-top-left-radius:0px;
}
.divenviareg{
    margin-top: 3px;
    min-width: 231px;
}
```

**Alguna idea de cómo alinear la palabra "Nuevo:" con el input del Rut en la resolución col-xs-12?**

Cualquier sugerencia para mejorar este formulario es bienvenida.

Comment: ¿Y si lo hacés flotar a la izquierda?

Comment: lo he intentado pero se desarma todo.

Comment: @RobertoSepúlvedaBravo Dentro de la línea de 12 puedes crear otra nueva línea que la divida en dos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**// Problemas**

Las razones por las que se "baja", son las siguientes:

1. A partir de **resoluciones menores a 768px**, los todas las reglas `form-*` para un `form.form-inline` dejan de tener efecto.
2. Ademas, las columnas con el estilo `col-xs-12` comienza a ocupar el `100% del width` y para que tu `#miform` de cierta forma siempre debe medir no mas y no menos de `240px`.

**// Solución**

1. Evita que los estilos para los `form-*` dentro del `form.form-inline` pierdan efecto poniendolos forzandolos para este "componente" para **resoluciones menores a 768px**.
2. Indicar un ancho `fijo` a `#miform`.

Ejemplo:

```css
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    #miform {
        min-width: 240px;
        max-width: 240px;
    }
    #miform.form-inline .form-group {
        display: inline-block;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
    #miform.form-inline .input-group {
        display: inline-table;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
    #miform.form-inline .input-group .form-control{
        vertical-align: middle;
        width: 100%;
    }
    #miform.form-inline .input-group .input-group-addon {
        width: auto;
    }
}

.form-group > #nuevito{
    color: white;
}
.form-group #nuevito span{
    padding-right: 10px;
}
.input-group{
    max-width: 230px;
}
.rut{
    max-width: 134px;
}
.emailpe{
    min-width: 230px;
}
.input-group-addon, .form-control, .enviareg{
    padding-top: 1px;
    padding-bottom: 1px;
    padding-left: 4px;
    padding-right: 6px;
    height: 25px;
}
.enviareg{
    width: 56px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:0px;
    border-top-left-radius:0px;
}
.divenviareg{
    margin-top: 3px;
    min-width: 231px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset='utf-8'>
<title>LosTurnos</title>

<!-- Bootstrap CSS-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- Bootstrap Tema opcional -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<!-- Bootstrap JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">

</head>

<body>
<div id="footer">
  <div class="navbar navbar-inner  navbar-fixed-bottom navbar-inverse mifooter">
    <p class="muted credit">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <form id="miform" action="trae_nuevo_empaque.php" class="form-inline">
              <div class="form-group">
    <label id="nuevito"><span>Nuevo:</span></label>
                <div class="input-group">
                  <div class="input-group-addon">Rut</div>
                  <input type="text" maxlength="8" class="form-control rut" placeholder="8 dígitos" required>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group">
                  <div class="input-group-addon">Nombre</div>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control nombre" placeholder="El primer nombre" required>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group">
                  <div class="input-group-addon">Apellido</div>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Un apellido" required>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group emailpe">
                  <div class="input-group-addon">E-Mail</div>
                  <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="email@algo.algo" required>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group divenviareg">
                  <div class="input-group-addon">Enviar correo de registro</div>
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info enviareg"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i></button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur ullam earum assumend</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Vitae quos ipsa distinctio asp.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Está buena esta solución, pero la idea es que en las resoluciones col-sm + no quede de la misma forma que en col-xs

Comment: He actualizado la respuesta restringiendo la aplicaciones de estilos a **resoluciones menores a 768px**

Answer (score 0):

Prueba este código:

```css
.form-group {
      max-width : 280px;
    }
    @media (min-width : 992px) {
      .form-group {
        max-width : 580px;
      }
      .col-left {
        padding-right: 5px;
      }
      .col-right {
        padding-left: 5px;
      }
    }
    .form-group #nuevito {
      color : white;
    }
    .input-group {
      width         : 100%;
      margin-bottom : 3px;
    }
    .divenviareg {
      margin-bottom : 0px;
    }
    .input-group-addon, .form-control, .enviareg {
      padding-top    : 1px;
      padding-bottom : 1px;
      padding-left   : 4px;
      padding-right  : 6px;
      height         : 25px;
    }
    .enviareg {
      width                     : 56px;
      border-bottom-left-radius : 0px;
      border-top-left-radius    : 0px;
    }
    .divenviareg > .input-group-addon {
      width : 100% !important;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
 
</head>
<body>
<div id="footer">
  <div class="navbar navbar-inner  navbar-fixed-bottom navbar-inverse mifooter">
    <p class="muted credit">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <form id="miform" action="trae_nuevo_empaque.php" class="form-inline">
        <div class="row form-group">
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-left">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2">
                <label id="nuevito"><span>Nuevo:</span></label>
              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-10">
                <div class="input-group">
                  <div class="input-group-addon">Rut</div>
                  <input type="text" maxlength="8" class="form-control rut" placeholder="8 dígitos" required>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="input-group">
              <div class="input-group-addon">Nombre</div>
              <input type="text" class="form-control nombre" placeholder="El primer nombre" required>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-right">
            <div class="input-group">
              <div class="input-group-addon">Apellido</div>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Un apellido" required>
            </div>
            <div class="input-group emailpe">
              <div class="input-group-addon">E-Mail</div>
              <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="email@algo.algo" required>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="input-group divenviareg">
              <div class="input-group-addon">Enviar correo de registro</div>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info enviareg">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i></button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Está bien hecho pero sigue quedando "Nuevo:" sobre el input del rut :/